# Kube-dns deployment changes are being reverted (GCE, K8S 1.5.2)

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

After upgrading GCE cluster to 1.5.2 I need to customise kube-dns configuration. I can save my changes to kube-dns deployment, but they are being reverted back to default after some time. I tried removing `kubernetes.io/cluster-service: "true"` labels with similar outcome — it reappears again after some time.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes 1.5 comes with a new system service called `kube-dns-autoscaler` ([documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-horizontal-autoscaling/)) that automatically adjusts the number of DNS replicas in your system based on the number of nodes and cores that your cluster has.

You can [tune the autoscaling parameters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-horizontal-autoscaling/#tuning-autoscaling-parameters) to indirectly adjust the number of DNS replicas rather than trying to adjust the number of replicas by modifying the kube-dns deployment directly.